# Passing a JSON file as environment variable to aws lambda update-function-configuration cli

Tags: linux, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am looking for a solution to pass a JSON file as environment variable to aws lambda update-function-configuration cli.

for example:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name "test" --environment var.json
```

and the variable JSON file would be:

```
{
  "Variables": {"string": "string",
    ...}
}
```

So, basically looking for a dynamic solution to insert environment variables to Lambda function via CLI.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried using Xargs but it did not help me:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the content of the `var.json` is as follow:

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
}
```

Then you can run the aws cli like this:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name "test" --environment "{\"Variables\":`cat var.json`}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `dev.json` file.

```
{
    "Variables": {
        "env": "dev",
        "interval_month": "1"
    }
}
```

And inside buildspec.yml file will be:

```
- aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name test-func-${STAGE} --environment "`cat ${STAGE}.json`"
```